# "He is the sinner of the main creation of the despute"

Tags: grammar, idioms

It sounds off and slightly wrong to my ears. Is it grammatically correct?

> Ryan is the sinner of the creation of the third dispute.

---

> Ryan is the sinner of the creation's third dispute.

---

I am trying to communicate that "Ryan is the one who started the third despute; he initiated it."
I am simply trying to write creatively.

---

To my knowledge, what I wrote is grammatically correct, however, it is written poorly. How can I rewrite it to make it sound more pleasurable, while still maintaining the "creativity". (This sounds weird.)

Comment: What do you think is wrong about it?

Comment: "It sounds off and slightly wrong to my ears." Don't you think so too?

Comment: What is it supposed to mean? As it stands it feels like a word salad to me, not a coherent sentence.

Comment: Yes. However, without further explanation of what you find grammatically incorrect or what you're trying to say, I don't know how to give feedback. What word, phrase, or feature sticks out to you? How have you tried to answer your question?

Comment: Please, see the updated question.

Comment: It's not "creative" to shoehorn the word ***sinner*** into a context like this. It's just silly. Best you concentrate on the basics, such as spelling ***dispute*** correctly.

Comment: *Ryan created the third dispute* or *Ryan was the third dispute's creator* or, if you really want to squeeze some *"sin"* into there somehow - *Ryan was guilty of creating the third dispute* ... any of those might suffice. Though it "feels" a bit weird to *create* a dispute, *initiate* might be better..?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean *center* and *dispute*?

Comment: @CD001: Nice one! I tried myself, but failed to come up with a "natural" English usage with "wrongdoing" implications.

Comment: The second version doesn't mean the same thing as the first. The second means that Ryan is the sinner *as discussed in* "the creation's third dispute." Just like Damien is the Antichrist of the film *The Omen*.

Answer (score 2):

This is not idiomatic.

1. We usually speak of *starting* a dispute or quarrel rather than *creating* it.

   > Ryan started the dispute.
2. *Sin* and *sinner* are used primarily to designate violation of religious prescriptions (or prescriptions treated jocularly or ironically as religious). You would do better to use some form of *blame* (noun or verb) or *fault*. There are a number of idioms that use these terms.

   - These all declare that [PERSON] bears the **primary** responsibility for an unhappy [SITUATION]:

     > *blame [PERSON] for [SITUATION]* — I blame Ryan for the dispute.
     >   *blame [PERSON] for [ACT<sup>ing</sup>]* — I blame Ryan for starting the dispute.
     >   *blame [SITUATION] on [PERSON]* — I blame the dispute on Ryan.
     >   *[SITUATION] be [PERSON]'s fault* — The dispute is Ryan's fault.
   - *at fault* usually declares that [PERSON] bears **some** responsibility for [SITUATION]:

     > *[PERSON] be at fault (for [ACT<sup>ing</sup>])* — Ryan is at fault for escalating the dispute.
   - *be to blame for [SITUATION/ACT<sup>ing</sup>]* is ambivalent. With [SITUATION] it usually assigns primary responsibility; with [ACT<sup>ing</sup>] it may assign either primary responsibility or only some.

     > Ryan is to blame for the dispute.
     >   Ryan is to blame for starting the dispute.